# How do you populate tabs in sequence from database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, database

This is probably an easy question but does anyone know how to insert data from a database into tabs autonomously ordered by a certain field?

Let me clarify, I need each tab to display data from my database ordered by the date they were added. So the latest in tab 1, the next in tab 2, and so on.

I've had this working in an accordion style where I did the database query first with a limit of five which repeated my code that inserted the info from the database up to five times. I have been trying to figure out a way similar to this except with tabs instead. Even if I could get a database query to put the latest result in tab 1, then do another query in tab 2 to find the second newest result, and so on.

Thanks for your time. Sorry if this is a silly question. :)

Sorry for leaving out code. What I am hoping to do is to call data from a database with code simular to

```
<?php       
        $subject_set = mysql_query("Select * FROM database WHERE column1 like 'value' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4", $connection);                  
        if (!$subject_set){
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
        while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)){?>

<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Tab #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab #4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab active">
        <?=$subject['column1']?>
        <?=$subject['column2']?>
        <?=$subject['column3']?>
        <?=$subject['column4']?> 
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2" class="tab">
        <?=$subject['column1']?>
        <?=$subject['column2']?>
        <?=$subject['column3']?>
        <?=$subject['column4']?> 
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3" class="tab">
        <?=$subject['column1']?>
        <?=$subject['column2']?>
        <?=$subject['column3']?>
        <?=$subject['column4']?> 
    </div> 

    <div id="tab-4" class="tab">
        <?=$subject['column1']?>
        <?=$subject['column2']?>
        <?=$subject['column3']?>
        <?=$subject['column4']?> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

I was hoping for code similar to this or probably only have one tab which is repeated depending on the limit in the database query.

Comment: Please post the code you have right now, we can help you correcting it... otherwise there are plenty of methods to do so, we can't telle you everything from scratch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the query:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM tableName ORDER BY dateColumn DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Let's assume you put this data into an array called `$data`.

If your tabs are HTML `<li>` elements then you can create a function for creating the HTML:

```
function buildList($data){
  $output = "";
  if(!empty($data)){
    $output .= "<ul>";
    foreach($data as $row){
      $output .= "<li>" . $row . "</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

I don't think I can provide any more detail without knowing the structure of your table, or the expected output.